# how to group by month in postgresql and rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have value like 2014/03/01, 2014/02/20, 2014/02/19, 2014/02/18, 2014/01/19 ...

And I wanna get sum(price) by month. For first month, second, third month, ...

Using rails 3 & postgresql.

I have tried  `@items = Item.where(:asin => @item.asin, :domain => @item.domain, :user_id => @item.user_id).order('created_at desc').group {created_at.beginning_of_month }`
didn't work.

I tried other stuff too, but it seems to be ignored, no group or group by in the log `SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."asin" = 'B00HI6ZLL2' AND "items"."domain" = 'co.jp' AND "items"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc`

Comment: if you give some code which you've already wrote, that might be helpful. Or how your model, controller look like?

Comment: Update :) I tried other stuff, but it seems to be ignored. I get in log SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."asin" = 'B00HI6ZLL2' AND "items"."domain" = 'co.jp' AND "items"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc

Comment: What i've learned from your question is that there is a price field in your item model, and you want to sum up the prices of each item which are created in the last three months. Am i correct?

Comment: I have data for 3 months now and I wanna get sum(price) for each month. In the future it'll be more than 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this but it will only work on a database that supports the `DATE_FUNC` function such as PostgreSQL and MySQL.  It won't work with SQLite.

```
@items = Item.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month, sum(price) AS total_price_per_month").group('month')
```

Comment: Looks like it did a trick :) Thank you.
Sorry :) one more, if I wanna group by year too, will it be ok?
@items = Item.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month,DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at) AS year, sum(price) AS total_price_per_month").group('month, year')

Comment: Yup :) Just tested it ;) It does work with year too :) Thank you mates for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = Array.new(12,0)
Item.each do |item|
  sum[item.created_at.month-1] += item.price  
end
```

Try this to get the every months item price sum. To fetch the February moths sum you get this from `sum[1]`

Comment: Thank you :) But I have to get sum(price) for each month :) & in the future it'll be more than 3 months, probably :)

Comment: I think that's what you want. :)